# Split a list into sublist by checking a condition on elements

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, list, functional-programming

Suppose I have an array of integeres and I want to split it into several parts, and I want to use zero as the condition on when to break. Something like this :

```
[1,2,3,0,4,5,0,6,7] => [[1,2,3,0], [4,5,0], [6,7]]
```

Well, it can be easily done using two for loops, but I wanted to know if it's possible to do this with LINQ.
There's a couple of question like this<sup>[[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419019/split-list-into-sublists-with-linq),[[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10826994/splitting-an-array-using-linq?rq=1)</sup>, but as opposed to this one, they rely on a condition that's been provided from outside of the list.

Note: I know it's not polite to ask more than one question in a thread, but if anyone out there is familiar with functional programming ( since in it's essence, it's really an FP question ), I'd also like to see their perspective and possible solutions for this problem.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have a dependency between separate elements of your collection, specifically, for each element you want to know "was the previous element a zero?". As soon as your query depends on the previous element (or, more generally, as soon as your query depends on other elements of the same sequence), you should reach for `Aggregate` (or in more general functional programming terms, `fold`). This is because `Aggregate`, unlike other LINQ operators, allows you to carry state with you from one iteration to the next.

So, to answer your question, I'd write this query as follows in LINQ.

```
// assume our list of integers it called values
var splitByZero = values.Aggregate(new List<List<int>>{new List<int>()},
                                   (list, value) => {
                                       list.Last().Add(value);
                                       if (value == 0) list.Add(new List<int>());
                                       return list;
                                   });
```

I'll break this down into parts so I can better explain my thinking.

```
values.Aggregate(new List<List<int>>{new List<int>()},
```

As I said before, reach for Aggregate because we need to carry state. Putting a new empty list into our List of Lists removes an edge case of the `List<List<int>>` having no lists in it.

```
(list, value) => {...}
```

Again, looking at the signature of our lambda expression (which is `Func<List<List<int>>, int, List<List<int>>`), we can see the state passing explicitly: we accept a `List<List<int>>` and return the same.

```
list.Last().Add(value);
```

Since we always want to work on the most recent `List<int>`, we get the `Last()` element of our list of lists (which will never be null due to the section above).

```
if (value == 0) list.Add(new List<int>());
```

This is where we do the splitting - on the next iteration, the call to Last() will return this new list.

```
return list;
```

And we finally pass the state on to the next iteration.

---

This could be generalized with little difficulty, in a `SplitOn` method, as follows:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> SplitOn<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    return source.Aggregate(new List<List<T>> {new List<T>()},
                            (list, value) =>
                                {
                                    list.Last().Add(value);
                                    if (predicate(value)) list.Add(new List<T>());
                                    return list;
                                });
}
```

The version using `IEnumerable`'s instead of `List`'s is somewhat less clear because of the way Enumerables work, but again, isn't particularly hard to create from the above code, and looks like (simplified just a touch via a ternary operator):

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> SplitOn<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    return source.Aggregate(Enumerable.Repeat(Enumerable.Empty<T>(), 1),
                            (list, value) =>
                                {
                                    list.Last().Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(value, 1));
                                    return predicate(value) ? list.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(Enumerable.Empty<T>(), 1)) : list;
                                });
}
```

---

You also might find [Haskell's implementation of splitOn](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/split-0.1.1/docs/src/Data-List-Split-Internals.html#splitOn) interesting, as it does exactly what you want. I would call it nontrivial (to put it lightly).

Comment: Unfortunately, the `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>` version doesn't work, because `.Concat()` doesn't alter the calling object like `.Add()` does, ergo the line (without `return`) does nothing and result is always empty. Lots of enumerable emptiness.

To remedy this while not complicating things too much, I've settled on building `IEnumerable<List<T>>`, using `.Add()` for the value and `.Concat()` for splitting lists.

Thanks for your answer nevertheless, it has been the most insightful.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an extension that helps:

```
public static IEnumerable<Tuple<TIn, int>> MarkWithLabels<TIn>(this IEnumerable<TIn> src, Predicate<TIn> splittingCondition)
{
    int label = 0;
    foreach (TIn item in src)
    {
        yield return new Tuple<TIn, int>(item, label);
        if (splittingCondition(item))
            label++;
    }
}
```

With it, the following does the trick

```
int breakingValue = 0;
var subseq = seq.MarkWithLabels(i => i == breakingValue)
    .GroupBy(tup => tup.Item2)
    .Select(group => group.Select(tup => tup.Item1).ToArray())
    .ToArray();
```

FP solution could be basically the same, except the foreach.

Answer (score 1):

I've compiled two extension methods based entirely on [Zack's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22849245/2979473) answer.

```
public static IEnumerable<List<T>> SplitBefore<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    return source.Aggregate(
        Enumerable.Repeat(new List<T>(), 1),
        (list, value) =>
        {
            if (predicate(value))
                list = list.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(new List<T>(), 1));
            list.Last().Add(value);
            return list;
        }
    )
    .Where(list => list.Any());
}


public static IEnumerable<List<T>> SplitAfter<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    return source.Aggregate(
        Enumerable.Repeat(new List<T>(), 1),
        (list, value) =>
        {
            list.Last().Add(value);
            return predicate(value)
                ? list.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(new List<T>(), 1))
                : list;
        }
    )
    .Where(list => list.Any());
}
```

Comment: That works perfectly, you and Zack deserve a very pleasant life :)